# Getting PottsWheel application for Matlab to create a new model creates an error

Tags: matlab, model

I have just installed PottersWheel (latest version) for Matlab (version R2014a) on 64-bit machine. When attempting to use the 'New Model' button I get an error which I have pasted below:

```
-------------------------------------------
Problem detected at 2014-10-17 14:06:01:
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Line  128 of pwGetFieldWidths.p
Line  170 of pwModel2CellArray.p
Line  126 of pwSaveModel.p
Line  607 of pwCreateModelGUI.p
Line  175 of pwCreateModelGUI.p
Line   95 of gui_mainfcn.m
Line   60 of pwCreateModelGUI.p
Matlab 2014a (mexw64) PottersWheel 3.1.0
-------------------------------------------
```

Since apparently there is no way to access .p files as they are protected. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The .p files are obfuscated MATLAB functions (or kind of object files). So, you cannot edit them. The possibilities are:

1. You read the documentation carefully, and verify that your arguments obey the requirements;
2. If #1 fails, you contact the author that holds the source and ask him/her for advice and bug fixing.
3. If #2 fails, you look for an de-obfucscator/de-compiler.